# fill an array from a specified starting point increasing by n increments

Tags: java, arrays

So let's say I want to count from "start" to "end" and increasing by 1 where start = 3 and end = 6. so the output should be: {3, 4, 5, 6}

here's my code so far

```
int[] myarray = new int[end - start + 1];
int start = 3;
int end = 6;
for (int a = 0; a < myarray.length; a++) {
    for (int i = start; start <= end; i++) {
        myarray[a] = i; 
    }
}
```

but the problem is that the nested for loop does not exit so it keeps on overwriting itself and I'm not sure how to make it 'exit'. any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using Java-8 probably the better way to do that like : `IntStream.range(start, end + 1).toArray();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem lies in the inner for-loop `for (int i = start; start <= end; i++)` You increase `i`, but you are checking `start<=end`. `start` does not change.

Further more your code would ouput an array with `{6,6,6,6}` because with the 2nd for loop you update the array always at the same position. You could just do something like this:

```
int start = 3;
int end = 6;
int[] myarray = new int[end - start + 1];
for (int a = 0; a < myarray.length; a++) {
    myarray[a] = start + a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the second loop is unnecessary, you can do it like this, also the `star` and `end` has to come before `myarray`

```
int start = 3;
int end = 6;
int[] myarray = new int[end - start + 1];
for (int a = 0; a < myarray.length; a++) {    
        myarray[a] = start+a; 
    }
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myarray));
```

**output**

```
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Edit : dont forget to import `Arrays` class to print arrays

```
import java.util.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using java-8 you don't need even 1 loop, all done in a single line.

```
int start = 3, end = 6;
int[] myarray = IntStream.rangeClosed(start, end).toArray();
```